# How to position a banner background image using img tag instead of inline-css ( position center of image)

Tags: css

I appreciate your help with css. I was placing my banner image using background-image with inline-css. I need now to place out using img tag and well to target the parent with css. Unfortunately my image doesn't resize as when it was inside the inline-css.

Here is my css code. Please see on full page and resize page.

The "effect" I like is that on mobile image only center of image is shown, while on increasing page width image is resized by keeping center of image as the base for the position. See second image of example (called banner-two).

So how to recreate exactly as the image in banner-two using background-image but now placing the image as img src.

I also created a codepen with my code ( [link to my code in codepen](https://codepen.io/tokyoweb/pen/PyGWxN) - please also resize ).

```css
.banner-two {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 240px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .banner-two {
  height: 480px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .banner-two {
  height: 680px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-one">
    <img alt="" src="https://pictr.com/images/2018/10/06/06cVw2.jpg"  />
</div>

<section>
<div class="banner-two" style="background-image: url('https://pictr.com/images/2018/10/06/06cVw2.jpg')"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: The below solution only works in Firefox; I can't seem to make it work in the other browsers.
I'll leave it up for now, in case it helps people in the right direction, but I'll delete it when a better working solution comes along.*

Just position the banner in the right place.

```css
.banner-one {
  height: 240px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.banner-one img {
  height: 100%;
}

.banner-two {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 240px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .banner-one,
  .banner-two {
    height: 480px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .banner-one,
  .banner-two {
    height: 680px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-one">
  <img alt="" src="https://pictr.com/images/2018/10/06/06cVw2.jpg" />
</div>

<section>
  <div class="banner-two" style="background-image: url('https://pictr.com/images/2018/10/06/06cVw2.jpg')"></div>
</section>
```

But the question is, why do you want to do this. You need a lot more CSS to make this work! My gut feeling would be to simply hide the img and then go on with what you were doing with banner-two. I can understand there being restraints that you have to work with though, so I hope this helps!

Comment: Mr Lister thanks for your guidance. Your code seems to work fine, I edited because on Chrome the img didn't expand more than original size, so I added a media to increase to width: 100vw at 1800px. I created a codepen with new code https://codepen.io/tokyoweb/pen/VEKbNB is working on mac safari, mac chrome and mac firefox. I don't know yet on windows, but my guess yes. Thanks a lot for your help. I do wonder why to use left: 50vw with transform -50% ? to force the browser to use the center of image as the base to position ?

Comment: The reason is I am now using lazy-loading javascript and img srcset then code is easier when using img tag. Code is now something like this... <img class="lazy" alt="" data-src="/path/image-500w.jpg" data-srcset="/path/image--1000w.jpg 768w, /path/image--2000w.jpg 1200w"  />

Answer (score 0):

```
.banner-one {
    width: 100%;
    height: 640px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.banner-one img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. For your help. Flex was one method I tried but I failed to make it work. See your code with flex vs transform https://codepen.io/tokyoweb/pen/XxjgJa Image is resized completely, as image is a a banner, then width is huge, then I would like just to show the center of image when browser width is small instead of resizing all image. Am I doing something wrong with your code ? Code flex called banner-flex, code below using transform called well banner-transform. I understand better flex than transform and I read flex is more efficient than to use transform. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Until now, here is the code. Banner-flex isn't working as image is being centered completely. Banner-transform is working fine. [link to examples on codepen](https://codepen.io/tokyoweb/pen/XxjgJa)

I do wonder if there is a way to do it that could be said is better or more efficient.

Thanks again !

```
<div class="banner-flex">
  <img alt="" src="https://pictr.com/images/2018/10/06/06cVw2.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="banner-transform">
  <img alt="" src="https://pictr.com/images/2018/10/06/06cVw2.jpg" />
</div>

.banner-flex {
width: 100%;
height: 240px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
.banner-flex img {
   max-width: 100%;
}

.banner-transform {
 height: 240px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 left: 50vw;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 }

.banner-transform img {
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .banner-flex,
 .banner-transform {
    height: 480px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.banner-flex,
.banner-transform {
    height: 680px;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1800px) {
.banner-transform img {
    width: 100vw;
 }
}
```